# PHP mysqli acting really screwy

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting to use PHP to connect to a database for the first time. I found an online tutorial that was teaching me how to use `mysqli` to do this. It talked about `mysqli_connect($host, $name, $pass, $db)` and that worked just fine. The problem was when the tutorial asked me to check for errors using the function `mysqli_connect_errno()` because apparently whatever version of PHP I am running doesn't recognize that function. But according to the internets, im the only weirdo who's copy of PHP is having this issue. Why can't my PHP recgonize `mysqli_connect_errno()`? (Note: I am running wampserver on a Windows 8.1 desktop and PHP version is 5.5.12) (UPDATE: the actual username is supossed to be "web")

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    $sql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sweb", "nsjk99", "Inventory");
    if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "( " . mysqli_connect_errorno() . ")");
    } else {
        echo "<p>Your connection was a success</p>";
    }
?>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are getting access denied error before the `errno` which means one of your connection strings is wrong. It could be that your username and password are correct, but the host should be something like: `localhost:3306` or `127.0.0.1` ...

Comment: I know that. That was on purpose. I was trying to test what happens when it fails

Comment: the fact that I couldn't get it to "fail properly" is the reason why this question exists in the first place

Comment: Ah that makes sense lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is called `mysqli_connect_errno()` and not `mysqli_connect_errorno()`, as you have on line 4.

> **Edit**

You don't need to pass the connection link as a parameter as stated [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php).

The function catches the error number from the last call to `mysqli_connect()`.

Thanks to [David Rosa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922156/david-rosa) for the warning.

Comment: Oh... Thank you very much.

Comment: The `mysqli_connect_errno()` function has no parameters http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php